# How can i get an users email id using Google Oauth2 Credentials of ‘Service Account’?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

How can I get an Google's user basic information using access token? Access token which is generated by an **service account** of Google. 
While I trying to get user info by using https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=xxxx..
which is returning the service accounts email and service accounts id.. which does not returning the user's **actual email id(anu@gmail.com)**..
How can I get the user's actual email id(**anu@gmail.com**) by this service accounts access token?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: a Service account is a dummy user so my guess is it doesn't have any user info.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a Google Apps account you want and the domain has granted your service account permission for the profile scope, you just need to use the sub= parameter to set the user you want an access token for. Then user profile calls will return data on the user instead of the service account. See [delegating domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).